# How to resize column width with autoFit in Kendo UI grid?

Tags: css, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI Grid for tables with autoFit to fit the columns' width to match their content and have them left-aligned (on a given page) for better readability. 
However I would like to add some space (sort of padding-left: 12px to each cell OR add 12px to the calculated columns' widths) to make the columns "breath".

As it seems the autoFit happens before the CSS is applied, doing it in CSS makes the table overflow by default (either horizontal scroll or pushes the table's width to the right).

My question:
Could someone tell me how to alter the columns' width BEFORE there are calculated by autoFit?